# Is it possible to use hibernate envers @Audited with r2dbc?

Tags: hibernate-envers, r2dbc, spring-data-r2dbc

I hope to achieve auditing of my tables using @Audited annotation of the Hibernate Envers project while I'm using Spring Data R2DBC or plain R2DBC to insert data into my tables.

Is this even feasible. I am not able to tell if Spring Data R2DBC uses hibernate at all.
I tried adding the @Audited annotation to my entity class to no avail.

```
this.fnclInfoRepository.save(itfnclinfo).subscribe();
```

```
@Data
@Builder
@Audited
public class Itfnclinfo implements Persistable<String> {
  @Id
  private String fnclInfoId;
..
}
```

I was expecting a new table created by hibernate with the suffix _AUD that holds the copy of all inserted data

Comment: What database is behind your R2DBC connection?   Is it MySQL, Postgres, H2, etc?

Comment: The database behind my R2DBC connection is Postgres. Since the original post, I have managed to implement auditing through regular inserts into separate audit tables.

Comment: I inquired about database platform because you could use Debezium to perform change-data-capture and transform those inserts into inserts into your audit tables asychronously which decouples that entirely from your application which is a nice separation in the long-run.

Answer (score 3):

I realize that Spring Data JPA is an abstraction over Hibernate and therefore Spring Data R2DBC is not a JPA provider abstraction and therefore not related to Hibernate. I'll have to come up with another way for auditing.

Comment: Hi do u find the solution for spring data envers replacement?

Comment: Hi @Sylvester have you found a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Spring data envers only works with traditional Spring Data JPA.

In a Spring Boot project, you can customize your `AuditEvent` and `AuditEventRepository` and setup the change log manually.

Check the Spring Boot docs - [Auditing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.auditing).

It maybe need more extra work, the good part is the auditevent is integrated with Spring Boot Actuator, you can track the auditevents by Actuator urls.